# aspell - Error No word lists can be found for the language

Tags: spell-checking

I am trying to use `aspell` to spell check a PDF file; I run the command:

```
aspell -c file.pdf
```

but I get the error:

> Errore: No word lists can be found for the language "it_IT".

My file is written in english: how can I tell this to `aspell`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `--lang` flag:

```
aspell --lang=en_US -c file.pdf
```

or:

```
LANG=en_US aspell -c file.pdf
```

---

From [`man aspell`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/aspell):

> `--lang=<string>, -l <string>`
>                           Language  to  use.  It follows the same format of the LANG environmental variable on most systems.  It consists of the two letter ISO 639 language code
>                 and an optional two letter ISO 3166 country code after a dash or underscore.  The default value is based on the value of the LC_MESSAGES locale.